# How to create stock move?

Tags: python, odoo-8, openerp-8

I tried to create stock move. This my script code:

```
if self.qty_abnormal > 0:
    move_data = {
        'product_id': self.batch_id.product_id.id,
        'product_uom_qty': self.qty_abnormal,
        'product_uom': self.batch_id.product_id.uom_id.id,
        'name': 'Selection: %s' % self.batch_id.product_id.display_name,
        'date_expected': self.selection_date,
        'location_id': self.picking_id.location_dest_id.id,
        'location_dest_id': self.culling_location_id.id,
        'state': 'confirmed', # set to done if no approval required
        'restrict_lot_id': self.batch_id.id # required by check tracking product
    }

    move = self.env['stock.move'].create(move_data)
    move.action_confirm()
    move.action_done()
```

and I clicked approve to move the stock, view error. and this my error :

> "null value in column "location_id" violates not-null constraint
>   Failing row contains (52, null, null, 2015-10-28 04:30:59.606056,
>   null, 1, null, 7.000, 1, 2015-10-28 04:30:59, null, null, null, 1,
>   null, null, null, confirmed, null, null, 2015-11-18 00:00:00, null,
>   Selection: [090901] Kecambah Dami Mas, 1, null, null, f, t, null,
>   make_to_stock, 1, 5, null, 56, null, null, null, 2015-10-28
>   04:30:59.606056, null, null, none, null). " while evaluating
>   u'action_approved()'

please help me.

Comment: Show your working model's class definition with fields.

Comment: i show my working model class. in answer

Comment: in which event you wrote this code (stock move create) ? it's in create method ?

Comment: yes it's in stock move create in my method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **picking** which your model referred doesn't contain **location_dest_id** or there is no **picking** selected in your model.

**Solution:**

- Keep picking mandatory field in your model by applying `required=True` in xml.
- You should also check conditions while evaluate code like below.

  `assert self.picking_id, "Picking is mandatory!!!"`
  `assert self.picking_id.location_dest_id, "Location must be there in picking!!!!"`

Don't know whether destination location is mandatory or not in stock.picking.

```
from openerp.exceptions import except_orm

@api.one
def action_move(self):
    """
    Selection do one actions:
    1. Move quantity of selection to culling location.
    """
    # Get unique location of planted location
    location_ids = set()
    for item in self.selectionline_ids:
        if item.location_id and item.qty_batch > 0: # todo do not include empty quantity location
            location_ids.add(item.location_id)

    if not self.picking_id or not self.culling_location_id:
        raise except_orm(_('Unable to process!'),_("Exception Message!!..."))
    if not self.picking_id.location_dest_id:
        raise except_orm(_('Unable to process!'),_("Exception Message!!..."))

    # Move quantity abnormal seed
    if self.qty_abnormal > 0:
        move_data = {
            'product_id': self.batch_id.product_id.id,
            'product_uom_qty': self.qty_abnormal,
            'product_uom': self.batch_id.product_id.uom_id.id,
            'name': 'Selection: %s' % self.batch_id.product_id.display_name,
            'date_expected': self.selection_date,
            'location_id': self.picking_id.location_dest_id.id,
            'location_dest_id': self.culling_location_id.id,
            'state': 'confirmed', # set to done if no approval required
            'restrict_lot_id': self.batch_id.id # required by check tracking product
        }

        move = self.env['stock.move'].create(move_data)
        move.action_confirm()
        move.action_done()

    return True
```

Comment: i follow your answer and errors same with first errors

Comment: I have posted solution please check it.

Comment: i follow your solution and view some other error : error like that : value error "exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str" while evaluating
u'action_approved()'

Comment: i found solution for my case, hihi, thanks for your answer,

Answer (score 0):

this my class model. and field

```
class Selection(models.Model):
"""Seed Selection"""
_name = 'estate.nursery.selection'

picking_id= fields.Many2one('stock.picking', "Picking", readonly=True)
lot_id = fields.Many2one('stock.production.lot', "Lot",required=True, ondelete="restrict", domain=[('product_id.seed','=',True)])
selectionline_ids = fields.One2many('estate.nursery.selectionline', 'selection_id', "Selection Lines")
batch_id = fields.Many2one('estate.nursery.batch', "Batch")
stage_id = fields.Many2one('estate.nursery.stage',"Stage")
selectionstage_id = fields.Many2one('estate.nursery.selectionstage',"Selection Stage",
                                    required=True)
qty_normal = fields.Integer("Normal Seed Quantity",)
qty_abnormal = fields.Integer("Abnormal Seed Quantity",)
date_plant = fields.Date("Planted Date",required=False,readonly=True,related='batch_id.date_planted',store=True)
qty_batch = fields.Integer("DO Quantity",required=False,readonly=True,related='batch_id.qty_received',store=True)
presentage_normal = fields.Float("Persentage Normal",digits=(2,2),required=False)
presentage_abnormal = fields.Float("Persentage Abnormal",digits=(2,2), required=False)
selection_date = fields.Date("Selection Date",required=True)
selection_type = fields.Selection([('0', 'Broken'),('1', 'Normal'),('2', 'Politonne')], "Selection Type")
selec = fields.Integer(related='selectionstage_id.age_selection')
maxa = fields.Integer(related='selectionstage_id.age_limit_max')
mina = fields.Integer(related='selectionstage_id.age_limit_min')
comment = fields.Text("Additional Information")
product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', "Product", related="lot_id.product_id")
nursery_information = fields.Selection([('draft','Draft'),
                                        ('0','untimely'),
                                        ('1','late'),('2','passed'),
                                        ('3','very late'),('4','very untimely')],
                                       compute='dateinformation', default='draft', string="Information Time" ,
                                       readonly=True,required=False)
nursery_lapseday = fields.Integer(string="Information Lapse of Day",
                                  required=False,readonly=True,compute='calculatedays',multi='sums',store=True)
nursery_lapsemonth = fields.Integer(string="Information Lapse of Month",
                                    required=False,readonly=True,compute='calculatemonth',multi='sums',store=True)
nursery_plandate = fields.Char('Planning Date',readonly=True,compute="calculateplandate",visible=True)
nursery_plandatemax = fields.Char('Planning Date max',readonly=True,compute="calculateplandatemax",visible=True)
nursery_plandatemin = fields.Char('Planning Date min',readonly=True,compute="calculateplandatemin",visible=True)
nursery_persentagen = fields.Float(digit=(2.2),compute='computepersentage')
nursery_persentagea = fields.Float(digit=(2.2),compute='computepersentage')
state = fields.Selection([
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('confirmed', 'Confirmed'),
    ('done', 'Done')], string="State")
culling_location_id = fields.Many2one('stock.location',("Culling Location"),
                                      domain=[('estate_location', '=', True),
                                              ('estate_location_level', '=', '3'),
                                              ('estate_location_type', '=', 'nursery'),('scrap_location', '=', True)])
```

Answer (score 0):

this my  action_approve()

```
@api.one
def action_approved(self):
    """Approved Selection is planted Seed."""
    self.action_receive()
    self.state = 'done'

@api.one
def action_receive(self):
    normal = self.qty_normal
    abnormal = self.qty_abnormal
    selectionlineids = self.selectionline_ids
    for item in selectionlineids:
        normal += normal
        abnormal += abnormal
    self.write({'qty_normal': self.qty_normal, 'qty_abnormal': self.qty_abnormal})
    self.action_move()
    return True
```

and this my action_move():

```
@api.one
def action_move(self):
    """
    Selection do one actions:
    1. Move quantity of selection to culling location.
    """
    # Get unique location of planted location
    location_ids = set()
    for item in self.selectionline_ids:
        if item.location_id and item.qty_batch > 0: # todo do not include empty quantity location
            location_ids.add(item.location_id)

    # Move quantity abnormal seed
    if self.qty_abnormal > 0:
        move_data = {
            'product_id': self.batch_id.product_id.id,
            'product_uom_qty': self.qty_abnormal,
            'product_uom': self.batch_id.product_id.uom_id.id,
            'name': 'Selection: %s' % self.batch_id.product_id.display_name,
            'date_expected': self.selection_date,
            'location_id': self.picking_id.location_dest_id.id,
            'location_dest_id': self.culling_location_id.id,
            'state': 'confirmed', # set to done if no approval required
            'restrict_lot_id': self.batch_id.id # required by check tracking product
        }

        move = self.env['stock.move'].create(move_data)
        move.action_confirm()
        move.action_done()

    return True
```

Comment: thanks you are not able to find that particular error point from where it raise exception ? this code seems fine but again `action_move()` is unknown for me.

Comment: do not post separate answer, update your question instead.

Comment: so, how  solution for my case? i really really stack.